# How to get the second commit message on powershell

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to get the second commit message only from a specific branch.

Here is the initial code so far.

```
$test = & { git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"%B" | tail -n -1 }
```

I am also trying to tail the second line but also it does not work

```
$test2 = $test.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine)
```

The output it is like this

```
COMMIT MESSAGE 1
COMMIT MESSAGE 2
```

But we only want to extract
`COMMIT MESSAGE 2`
to store as variable

Thank you

Comment: instead of piping to `tail`, try piping to `Select-Object -Last 1`

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon the Select-Object function does not work. I run it via powershell on Azure DevOps btw if it helps

Comment: I'm unsure about if Azure DevOps is changing the output type of `git` for some reason. `Select-Object -Last 1` does work for me when running locally. Does it work for you if running locally ? `git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"%B" | select -last 1`

Comment: @Dan another option is to index the last option of the array: `(git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"%B")[-1]`. Does the same as `select -last 1`

Comment: There was a glaring error in my answer: `"\`1"` doesn't actually create a `[char] 1`, but verbatim `1`. This is now fixed, and extraction of potentially multiline messages should work robustly.

Answer (score 0):

- Commit messages can be *multiline*.
- Thus, use a self-chosen delimiter that is unlikely to occur in the messages themselves to *delimit them* in the output, such as `[char] 1` (START OF HEADING, [`U+0001`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/charz/1)).
- In combination with converting `git`'s output - which, as any external-program's output in PowerShell, streams *line by line* -  to a *single, multiline* string via [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string), you can then use the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator with the self-chosen delimiter to split the string into the individual commit messages.
- [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with its (`0`-based) `-Index` parameter then allows you to select the message(s) of interest.
- Finally, you can use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) to call the [`.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Trim) method on each resulting message in order to remove surrounding whitespace.

```bash
(git log --pretty=format:"$([char] 1)%B" | Out-String) -split [char] 1 | 
  Select-Object -Index 2  |  # Get the 2nd message.
  ForEach-Object Trim        # Remove surrounding whitespace.
```

Note:

- While the `-Index` parameter is `0`-based, `2` still selects the *second* message in the command above, because the `-split` operation creates an *empty first element* as an artifact.
- An equivalent, expression-based formulation of the above:

  ```bash
  ((git log --pretty=format:"$([char] 1)%B" | Out-String) -split [char] 1)[2].Trim()
  ```
- `-n 2`, for selecting only 2 messages, is omitted from `git log` above, both for brevity and so you don't have to worry about keeping this argument in sync with the `-Index` argument; however, the following approach is an alternative that uses `Select-Object -Last 1` / index `[-1]` to select the *last* message from whatever `git -log -n <n>` outputs:

  ```bash
  (git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"$([char] 1)%B" | Out-String) -split [char] 1 |
    Select-Object -Last 1 |
    ForEach-Object Trim

  # Expression-based equivalent 
  ((git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"$([char] 1)%B" | Out-String) -split [char] 1)[-1].Trim()
  ```